# Need to add buttons to a frame. What is wrong with this java code?

Tags: java, swing, calculator

I NEED to write a Calculator in Java, and ofc I am stuck with adding buttons to a layout. What is wrong with this code? I am trying to add 10 buttons to a GridBagLayout with a for loop. I am using Eclipse, and it is only stating that there is an error, though it doesn't identify the error at all.
Thanks!

```
some import stuff

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private GridBagConstraints grid;
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private JButton[] button=new JButton[10];


    public Calculator(){                
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Size"));
        grid=new GridBagConstraints();  
        this.setSize(300,250);
        this.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);         
        for (int i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {  
            button[i] = new JButton(""+i);  
            button[i].add(button[i],grid);          
            button[i].addActionListener(this);  
         }  

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Calculator calcFrame=new Calculator();
        calcFrame.setVisible(true);                     

    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }   
};
```

Comment: It's not saying only that "there is an error". Open the "Problems" view, and read/post the complete error message that is displayed in this view. If it's a runtime problem and not a compilation problem, then you get a stack trace. Read it and post it.

Comment: Your problem is an honest problem, but your question could use improvement. Next go-around, please post your complete error messages, please make a better question heading, one that summarizes the problem itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Components can't be their own container in Swing. Add the buttons to the `mainPanel` rather than to the components themselves

```
mainPanel.add(button[i], grid);
```